# How do i use Specified Data as an axis in excel

Tags: excel, graph

I have a question about doing a graph in excel, i im trying to make a representation of an accelerometer. in this i have 4 values X,Y,Z and time between measurements.

> X=1,039 Y=8,743 Z=4,747 TIMEms=4

I have 600+ value sets like this and i want to make 3 graphs for X,Y,Z with TIMEms as the distance between each datapoint on the horizantal axiz. How can i do this? 
I tried using the values of TIMEms but this just gives me a horizontal axis consisting of 5's with the default distance of 1 between them.

Comment: I might be missing something here, but are you just asking if you need an XY plot? Y being yout X/Y/Z values and X being the Time?

Comment: You have in fact X,Y,Z, and T - so four dimensions. You told us how you want to plot T, but how do you want to plot the other three dimensions?

Comment: the value of X,Y,Z determines the vertical plot and the horizontal plot should be a timeline from 0-(samplesize in ms) where T is the interval in ms between each sample.
first sample at 0ms second at 4ms third at 9ms and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you currently have a sheet with columns X, Y, Z and TIMEms, you'll need to add a new column to the end to roll-up all the time differences.

Let's assume you have this sheet, and TIMEms is column D. In column E, label it "Time" in cell E1, and in E2 set this equal to zero. E3, set to the formula:

```
= E2 + D2
```

Copy/paste this formula down the column (assumes the time quoted in column D is the time since the last observation, rather than time until next observation). You should now see time increase down this column as a "milliseconds since recording began".

Next you'll need to insert a scatter chart (whichever flavour you prefer), setting the X-values to be the values in column E, and the Y values to be whichever of the X/Y/Z values you want to plot. On the "Insert" ribbon, in the "Charts" area, look for the graph looking like a bunch of unconnected points - hover over it and it should say "Insert scatter (X,Y) or Bubble chart" - select one of the scatter charts.

When you have the chart object, you need to wire up the data correctly with the "Select Data" UI you get access from when right-clicking on the chart object. Click "Add" and you get a dialog prompting you for the series name, the X-values and the Y-values - enter appropriate ranges in those boxes, for example X-values would be "=E2:E600", and Y-values "=B2:B600", to plot the actual Y values.

You can also add more series to the chart to get each of X, Y and Z on the same chart, if you so desire.